# Enable PostGIS extension error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have PostGIS 2.0.4 installed with PostgreSQL 9.2.4, trying to enable spatial database extension with the following command:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

but encountered an error -

> ERROR: must be owner of type spheroid

What is this spheroid type? How could I enable it?

## Update:

Well, I still couldn't find a solution so I had to remove everything and reinstall again. Now I am getting a new error saying:

> ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.2/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": libclntsh.so.11.1 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have no luck google out an answer to this. It seems *libclntsh.so.11.1* is a Oracle library? Why it has something to do with PostgreSQL?

Comment: The `spheroid` type is provided by PostGIS. On what OS? How did you install Postgres/PostGIS?

Comment: I installed postgresql through rpm on RHEL6.2 and postgis was hand built from source. I didn't do much of configuration, just ./configure then make -> make install.

Comment: Hmm, I've built it many times, but I've never seen this error. Take a look at http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall for different methods of building/installing. Also, the PGDG RPMs are pretty good quality.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging in as a db superuser.  On Linux the following should work on most distros:

```
sudo postgres psql [dbname]
```

Then ownership and permissions can be effectively ignored.  In general I would recommend doing this for most extension installations as this usually requires superuser privileges anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but now get: `ERROR:  relation "spatial_ref_sys" already exists`. After dropping that table and running `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` I get: `"geometry_columns" is not a view`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but I want an answer here for the next time ***I*** run into it!

Drop the **tables** `spatial_ref_sys` and `geometry_columns`. They shouldn't be *tables* in your schema. In my case, they got created as an artefact of using DotNet to create Entity Framework models from a SQL Server database, then using EF to recreate the DB in Postgres.

So:

```
sudo postgresql psql [dbname] -c "drop table spatial_ref_sys; drop table geometry_columns; create extension postgis;"
```